# How to Setup gpg signing on vscode devcontainer without forwarding to local

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, gnupg, vscode-remote, gpg-agent

Is there a way to setup gpg in vscode docker container without the remote-containers extension automatically forwaridng gpg signing (because i could not get it to work)?

I am using vscode 1.56.2 and remote-containers 0.177.2

thanks